# Recursion and return statements in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, return

I am trying to implement a 2-3 tree but I am having trouble with the find method.
This method given an int as parameter should return the node that contains the int.
The problem is that sometimes it works, sometimes it does't and I don't know why.
I have added a test print. For a particular int that I know for sure that is part of the tree, the code executes the print statement, meaning that it has found the node, but does not return this node. Instead it return False which is at the end of the code.

Can you help me solving this ?

```
def find(self,data,node=0): #return problem ???

    if node==0:
        a=self.root
    else:
        a=node

    if a.data2==None:
        if data==a.data:   ### here is the problem
            print("qwertyuiop") ### it does not execute the return statement
            return a
        elif data < a.data:
            if a.left!=None:
                return self.find(data,a.left)
        elif data > a.data:
            if a.right!=None:
                return self.find(data,a.right)

    else:
        if a.data2!=None:
                if (data==a.data or data==a.data2):
                    return a
                elif data<a.data:
                    if a.left!=None:
                        return self.find(data,a.left)
                elif (data>a.data and data<a.data2):
                    if a.middle!=None:
                        return self.find(data,a.middle)
                elif data>a.data2:
                    if a.right!=None:
                        return self.find(data,a.right)
    print("Not Found") ### function executes this print
    return False
```

self.root is the root of the tree and is an object of the following class

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.data2 = None
        self.data3 = None
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.middle = None
        self.middle2 = None
```

Binary Search Tree:

```
class Nodeee:

def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right

class BST:


def __init__(self, root=None):
    self.c=[]
    self.total=0
    self.root = None


def parent(self,data,node=5):

    def search(nodee,cc,data):

        if data==cc.data:
            return nodee
        else:
            if data<cc.data:
                nodee=cc
                return search(nodee,cc.left,data)
            elif data>cc.data:
                nodee=cc
                return search(nodee,cc.right,data)

        print("Parent Error")
        return False

    if node==self.root:
        print("Root has no parent")
    else:
        a=self.root
        c=self.root
        return search(a,c,data)


def lookup(self,data,node=0):

    if node==0:
        a=self.root
    else:
        a=node

    if data < a.data:
        if a.left==None:
            return a
        else:
            return self.lookup(data,a.left)
    elif data > a.data:
        if a.right==None:
            return a
        else:
            return self.lookup(data,a.right)

def find(self,data,node=0):

    if node==0:
        a=self.root
    else:
        a=node

    if data==a.data:
        print("WTF")
        return a
    elif data < a.data:
        if a.left!=None:
            return self.find(data,a.left)
    elif data > a.data:
        if a.right!=None:
            return self.find(data,a.right)
    print("Not Found")
    return False

def find2(self,data,node=0):

    if node==0:
        a=self.root
    else:
        a=node

    if data==a.data:
        return True
    elif data < a.data:
        return self.find2(data,a.left)
    elif data > a.data:
        return self.find2(data,a.right)
    return False

def is_empty(self):
    if self.root==None:
        return True


def is_leaf(self,n):
    if (n.left==None and n.right==None):
        return True
    return False

def delete(self):
    self.root=None

def insert(self, data):

    if self.root==None:
        self.root=Nodeee(data)
        self.total+=1
        return True
    else:
        b=self.lookup(data)
        if data < b.data:
            b.left=Nodeee(data)
            self.total+=1
            return True
        elif data > b.data:
            b.right=Nodeee(data)
            self.total+=1
            return True
    print("Insert Error !")
    return False


def inorder_swap(self,data):
    a=self.find(data)
    b=a.right
    while self.is_leaf(b)!=True:
        if b.left!=None:
            b=b.left
        elif b.left==None:
            b=b.right
    temp=a.data
    a.data=b.data
    b.data=temp

def remove(self,data):
    a=self.find(data)
    if self.is_leaf(a)==True:
        b=self.parent(data)
        if b.left==a:
            b.left=None
        elif b.right==a:
            b.right=None
    elif self.is_leaf(a)==False:
        if a.left==None:
            b=self.parent(data)
            if b.left==a:
                b.left=b.left.right
            elif b.right==a:
                b.right=b.right.right
        elif a.right==None:
            b=self.parent(data)
            if b.left==a:
                b.left=b.left.left
            elif b.right==a:
                b.right=b.right.left
        elif (a.left!=None and a.right!=None):
            self.inorder_swap(data)
            self.remove(data)

def inorder(self,node):
    if node!=None:
        self.inorder(node.left)
        self.c.append(node.data)
        self.inorder(node.right)

def inorder_print(self):
    self.c=[]
    self.inorder(self.root)
    print("\nStart")
    for x in range(len(self.c)):
            print(self.c[x], end=",")
    print("\nFinish\n")




a=BST()
print(a.insert(234)==True)
print(a.insert(13)==True)
print(a.insert(65)==True)
print(a.insert(658)==True)
print(a.insert(324)==True)
print(a.insert(86)==True)
print(a.insert(5)==True)
print(a.insert(76)==True)
print(a.insert(144)==True)
print(a.insert(546)==True)
print(a.insert(2344)==True)
print(a.insert(1213)==True)
print(a.insert(6345)==True)
print(a.insert(653348)==True)
print(a.insert(35324)==True)
print(a.insert(8463)==True)
print(a.insert(5555)==True)
print(a.insert(76539)==True)
print(a.insert(14499)==True)
print(a.insert(59999946)==True)

a.inorder_print()
a.remove(35324)
a.remove(1213)
a.remove(2344)
a.remove(144)
a.remove(5555)
a.remove(6345)
a.remove(59999946)
a.remove(76)
print(a.root.data)
a.inorder_print()
```

Comment: The return statement does not get executed ! It also prints the "Not found" at the end of the code.

Comment: If it doesn't print `"qwertyuop"` and prints `Not Found`, that means either it's really not found, or your function just can't find it.

Comment: How many times does it print `Not Found`?

Comment: @qla_alp Could you provide some code that instantiates some `Node` objects and runs `find`, but fails to find something when it should?

Comment: It prints both "qwertyuop" and "Not Found" !

Comment: Find is used by another method, which is "remove". Inside the remove method I just do a=self.find(int). I know for sure that this int is in the tree. When I do for example a.data it prints Bool has no attribute data.

Comment: @qla_alp Please show us a full example of usage. You most likely have an error creating your tree.

Comment: Full code is very long, around 400 lines !

Comment: @qla_alp Without an example that breaks, there is no way for anyone to help you. On the surface, it looks like there is no problem with the algorithm of the `find` method. However, the `find` method it not robust against Node objects that are incorrectly constructed (for instance if left/right tress are accidentally switched). Without further code, the best that can be said is that your constructed Tree is faulty.

Comment: Then shorten it, so it still runs on its own, but produces the problem. Post at least, `remove` and how you call it as well as the tree initialization.

Comment: @Nabla I added a binary search tree version which is smaller, but gives me the same problem when I try to remove.

Comment: @three_pineapples I added a shorter code version but with same problem, do you have any ideas about what the error might be ?

Comment: This code has `find`, `loopkup`, `find2` and `search`, all of which seem to do the same. Why so complicated?

Answer (score 1):

```
def inorder_swap(self,data):
    a=self.find(data)
    b=a.right
    while self.is_leaf(b)!=True:
        if b.left!=None:
            b=b.left
        elif b.left==None:
            b=b.right
    temp=a.data
    a.data=b.data
    b.data=temp
```

`a` here is the node containing the passed `data`. This method does nothing else than swapping `a`'s `data` with some leaf's `data` (first one while finds), thereby distorting the tree order. A follow-up `find` on the same `data` therefore fails and returns `False`. Since your code has no error checks, this results in an `AttributeError`.

You probably want to move nodes around in `inorder_swap`. However you only assign to the local name `b`. If you want to change nodes, then you need to use `b.left =` or `b.right =`.

It might be that there are more problems, that I don't see right now.

Also your code has several style problems, some of them:

1. You have four functions doing the same: `find`, `find2`, `lookup` and `search` in `parent`.
2. Most of the naming is not informative or even confusing.
3. Lines like `if a.right==None:` should be written as `if not a.right:` (or maybe `if a.right is None:`).
4. Check the return value of functions and don't just assume they return a valid node if they might not (i.e. `find` might return `False` instead of a node). Or alternatively use exception handling.
5. If you have an `if ... elif ... elif` block you don't have to check the last possibility if it is sure to be true, for example:

   ```
    if b.left!=None:
         # something
    elif b.left==None:
         # something else
   ```

   should be

   ```
    if b.left:
         # something
    else:
         # something else
   ```